# Reading from commandLine and print distinct values in list

Tags: scala

I have to pass a list of numbers on the command line and it should print out the distinct value in the list.

```
object Dup {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val list = args.map(_.toInt)
    val distinct = list.distinct
    println("Distinct: "+distinct)
  }
}
```

The expected result should be like

```
Input $ scala dup.scala 1 3 5 3 7 3 1 1 5
Output 1 3 5 7
```

Actual:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For 
input string: "1,2,1,3,1"
```

Comment: Why use `.toInt`? Why not just `println("Distinct: " + args.distinct.mkString(" "))`?

Comment: The error says it can't convert commas into integers. Where did the commas come from? Are you adding them when you type the input?

Comment: because of comma it's giving you the NumberFormatException

Answer (score 0):

If you are taking command line args like this "1,2,3,4,5,6"

this should work:

```
  object DemoAbc extends App {
  val ar: List[Option[Int]] = args.toList.flatMap(_.split(",")).map(_.toIntOption).distinct
  ar.foreach(println)
}
output: Some(1)Some(2)Some(3)Some(4)Some(5)Some(6)
```

if you want to remove those Some too you can use this:

```
object DemoAbc extends App {
  val ar: List[Int] = args.toList.flatMap(_.split(",")).flatMap(_.toIntOption).distinct
  ar.foreach(print)
}
output 123456
```

this will return all the Integers which can be converted if you will give args like this:
"1,2,3,4,5,6,%"

it will produce the same output without Some(value).

I hope it helps